# ¿Cómo agregar y remover clases en los eventos mouseover y mouseout, solo con JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Me gustaría saber si este fragmento de código se puede hacer sin jQuery.

```
$(".container").mouseover(()=>{
    $(".icon").addClass("container2")
})
$(".container").mouseout(()=>{
    $(".icon").removeClass("container2")
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery está escrito en JavaScript, entonces la pregunta de si un código jQuery es posible hacerlo con solo JS es siempre afirmativa.

Para `$('.clase');` puedes usar `document.getElementsByClassName('clase');`, pero devolverá un `HTMLCollection` con los elementos y tendrás que iterar por cada uno. Yo usaría `Array.from()` para convertirlo en un array y entonces usar `.forEach`.

`$elemento.mouseover()` -> `elemento.addEventListener('mouseover');`

`$elemento.mouseout()` -> `elemento.addEventListener('mouseout');`

`$elemento.addClass('container2');` -> `elemento.classList.add('container2');`

`$elemento.removeClass('container2');` -> `elemento.classList.remove('container2');`

```js
const contenedores = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('container'));

contenedores.forEach(elemento => {
  elemento.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    const iconos = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('icon'));
    iconos.forEach(icon => icon.classList.add('container2'))
  });
});

contenedores.forEach(elemento => {
  elemento.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    const iconos = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('icon'));
    iconos.forEach(icon => icon.classList.remove('container2'))
  });
});
```

```css
.container2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Pasa el raton por aqui</div>
<div class="icon">Icon 1</div>
<div class="icon">Icono 2</div>
```

Documentación:

- `getElementsByClassName()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
- `addEventListener()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
- `classList` (include los métodos `.add()` y `.remove()`): https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList